# Munging a dict into a Pandas DataFrame containing Hierarchical index and columns

Tags: python, pandas

I'm attempting to munge the dictionary below into a preferable DataFrame format for easy on the eyes viewing. That data dict was created after accessing an api and parsing XML so i'm certainly willing to put the data together differently to make the process easier.

The format I have is this (with the other two markets not shown placed horizontally beside each other):

```
                    Market1
                          B                      S
                     Depth1 Depth2  Depth3  Depth1  Depth2  Depth3
actionIndicator           B      B       B       S       S       S
limit                   589    588     586     591     592     593
quantity            185.121  8.121  32.216  34.805  16.037  36.099
```

The format I want is (the two markets not shown should be vertically stacked and note re-ordering of depths):

```
                                  B                      S
                             Depth3 Depth2  Depth1  Depth1  Depth2  Depth3
Market1    actionIndicator        B      B       B       S       S       S
           limit                587    588     589     591     592     593
           quantity         185.121  8.121  32.216  34.805  16.037  36.099
```

Code:

```
from pandas import DataFrame


data = {
 'Market1': {'B': {'Depth1': {'actionIndicator': 'B',
    'limit': '558',
    'quantity': '8.286'},
   'Depth2': {'actionIndicator': 'B', 'limit': '557', 'quantity': '8.355'},
   'Depth3': {'actionIndicator': 'B', 'limit': '555', 'quantity': '18.474'}},
  'S': {'Depth1': {'actionIndicator': 'S',
    'limit': '560',
    'quantity': '0.626'},
   'Depth2': {'actionIndicator': 'S', 'limit': '561', 'quantity': '17.101'},
   'Depth3': {'actionIndicator': 'S', 'limit': '562', 'quantity': '17.576'}}},
 'Market2': {'B': {'Depth1': {'actionIndicator': 'B',
    'limit': '478',
    'quantity': '8.182'},
   'Depth2': {'actionIndicator': 'B', 'limit': '477', 'quantity': '8.329'},
   'Depth3': {'actionIndicator': 'B', 'limit': '475', 'quantity': '30.156'}},
  'S': {'Depth1': {'actionIndicator': 'S',
    'limit': '479',
    'quantity': '37.483'},
   'Depth2': {'actionIndicator': 'S', 'limit': '480', 'quantity': '84.416'},
   'Depth3': {'actionIndicator': 'S', 'limit': '481', 'quantity': '37.659'}}},
 'Market3': {'B': {'Depth1': {'actionIndicator': 'B',
    'limit': '587',
    'quantity': '8.18'},
   'Depth2': {'actionIndicator': 'B', 'limit': '586', 'quantity': '8.382'},
   'Depth3': {'actionIndicator': 'B', 'limit': '583', 'quantity': '39.548'}},
  'S': {'Depth1': {'actionIndicator': 'S',
    'limit': '589',
    'quantity': '55.181'},
   'Depth2': {'actionIndicator': 'S', 'limit': '590', 'quantity': '17.289'},
   'Depth3': {'actionIndicator': 'S', 'limit': '591', 'quantity': '17.689'}}},
}

df = DataFrame.from_dict(
        {(k1, k2, k3): data[k1][k2][k3] for k1 in data.keys() for k2 in
         data[k1].keys() for k3 in data[k1][k2].keys()}, orient="columns")

print(df)
```

Comment: Have you looked at pd.melt?

Comment: Hacky but works: `df.unstack().reorder_levels([0,3,2,1]).unstack(level=[3,2])`

Comment: Thanks Jan. Any hope of re-ordering that one section of 'depths'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df = df.unstack().reorder_levels([0,3,2,1]).unstack(level=[3,2])

dfB = df[["B"]].sort_index(axis=1, ascending=False)
dfS = df[["S"]]

df = pd.concat([dfB, dfS], axis=1)
```

50% of credit goes to Jan who commented with the unstack() solution.

Gives:

```
                              B                     S
                         Depth3 Depth2 Depth1  Depth1  Depth2  Depth3
Market1 actionIndicator       B      B      B       S       S       S
        limit               555    557    558     560     561     562
        quantity         18.474  8.355  8.286   0.626  17.101  17.576
Market2 actionIndicator       B      B      B       S       S       S
        limit               475    477    478     479     480     481
        quantity         30.156  8.329  8.182  37.483  84.416  37.659
Market3 actionIndicator       B      B      B       S       S       S
        limit               583    586    587     589     590     591
        quantity         39.548  8.382   8.18  55.181  17.289  17.689
```